# jqGrid - always select first row using setSelection is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am populating jqgrid with data on page load and trying to set the first row always selected in but, for some reason it is not working.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/116/

```
var customGrid = jQuery("#sg1");

customGrid.jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    gridview: true,
    loadonce: true,
    shrinkToFit: false,
    autoencode: true,
    height: 'auto',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    scrollrows: true,
    loadui: 'disable',
    idPrefix: "cg_",
    colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int"},
        {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date"},
        {name:'name',index:'name', width:80},
        {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
        {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},     
        {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"},      
        {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}       
    ],
    caption: "Test Grid"
});

var mydata = [
        {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test 1234567890123456789",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
        {id:"2",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}
        ];

customGrid[0].addJSONData(mydata);

//set the first row always selected on initial load
customGrid.jqGrid('setSelection', 1);
```

**Expectation:**

First row should be selected.

Am I missing anything? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have set the idPrefix in my jqGrid. I have updated the setSelection as

`customGrid.jqGrid('setSelection', 'cg_1');` and the first row selection works now.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove following setting:

```
idPrefix: "cg_",
```

You can try my version. Please make sure you have jquery-ui library loaded properly. When the *idPrefix* is set then it can't set the class called *ui-state-highlight* to the row using just *ID*.

```
var jgrid = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
    datatype: "json",
    gridview: true,
    loadonce: true,
    shrinkToFit: false,
    autoencode: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    scrollrows: true,
    loadui: 'disable',
    colNames:['Inv No','Date', 'Client', 'Amount','Tax','Total','Notes'],
    colModel:[
       {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int"},
       {name:'invdate',index:'invdate', width:90, sorttype:"date"},
       {name:'name',index:'name', width:80},
       {name:'amount',index:'amount', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
       {name:'tax',index:'tax', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
       {name:'total',index:'total', width:80,align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
       {name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false}
    ],
    width: 1280,
    height: 'auto',
    rowNum: 150,
    caption: "Test Grid"
});
var mydata = [
    {id:"1",invdate:"2007-10-01",name:"test 1234567890123456789",note:"note",amount:"200.00",tax:"10.00",total:"210.00"},
    {id:"2",invdate:"2007-10-02",name:"test2",note:"note2",amount:"300.00",tax:"20.00",total:"320.00"}
    ];
    jgrid[0].addJSONData(mydata);
    jgrid.jqGrid('setSelection', 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I need the idPrefix. So, I have updated the setSelection as customGrid.jqGrid('setSelection', 'cg_1'); and it works now.